# Run a cron job to import many csv files in docker mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, cron, docker-compose, sh

My database in running inside a docker container and i want to load data from csv files into the database every hour

Inside the container runs this script perfect manually, but i can't start a ron job inside the mysql container.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /import/logs/301
for f in *.csv
do
        mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$f"' IGNORE INTO TABLE 301 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (@date,@time,R3,R2,R1) SET MeasuringTime = timestamp(str_to_date(@date,'%Y/%m/%d'), @time)" -u USER --password=PASSWORD DATABASE
done

cd /import/logs/302
for f in *.csv
do
        mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$f"' IGNORE INTO TABLE 302 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (@date,@time,R3,R2,R1) SET MeasuringTime = timestamp(str_to_date(@date,'%Y/%m/%d'), @time)" -u USER --password=PASSWORD DATABASE
done
```

I prefer to run the cron on the host, but how?

Or should i take a extra import container, how would you build the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Running more than one process in a single docker container is usually a bad practice.
(you can read about it in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) if you're really interested)

#### Option 1 - dedicated container for the cron job

Your best option is to create another container that will do this job (of course, you'll have to link between them and make sure you have mysql installed on your new docker container etc)

For the new container, check Jon Ribeiro's article on how to run cron jobs inside docker https://jonathas.com/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-on-docker/

#### Option 2 - running the cron job on the host

Alternatively, if you want to run cron on your host, you'll have to expose the mysql container ports to the host, and connect to to it.

Do note that mysql on a linux host will use unix socket if it tries to connect to localhost, so use `mysql --host=localhost --protocol=TCP` as explained in mysql documentation
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html
From mysql documentation:

> On Unix, the client connects using a Unix socket file. The --socket option or the MYSQL_UNIX_PORT environment variable may be used to specify the socket name.
>
> To force a TCP/IP connection to be used instead, specify a --protocol option:
> shell> `mysql --host=localhost --protocol=TCP`